# Complex exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

How do I solve:
$$
e^{4z}+e^{3z}+e^{2z}+e^z+1=0
$$

I'm getting lost on where to start. I tried using the definition
$$
e^z=e^x(\cos(y) +i\sin(y)) 
$$

But that doesn't seem to do me any good. I also tried using complex powers, but I seem to just be going in circles. Any suggestions?